# Can not run React Native app after uninstall it on ios simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, react-native-ios

my problem is as follow:

My React Native app is created using **react-native init** command. I can debug it on iOS simulator already using **react-native run-ios** command.

But I've just uninstalled it on the simulator, and now I can't run it again using **react-native run-ios** command. My simulator and the packager are still there, but nothing happens.

I've tried to re-run simulator, change another version of iOS on simulator, change another version of simulator (iPhone version) but none of those work. Hope anyone can help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around, I found the built file, located at **/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/[ProjectName].app**. Then I drag and drop it onto the simulator, the app is intalled instantly and I can run it again, phew